# VMR9 imposing wrong video size on captured file

Tags: c++, directshow, video-capture

I have the following code, which I'm trying to use to capture from a webcam and at the same time previewing the video (**pRenderer** points to a windowed VMR9 filter, and **mPMux** to a mux returned by **ICaptureGraphBuilder2::SetOutputFileName**):

```
hr = mPBuild->RenderStream(
    &PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW,
    &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    mPCapVideo,
    NULL,
    pRenderer);

hr = mPBuild->RenderStream(
    &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,
    &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    mPCapVideo,
    NULL,
    mPMux);
```

Although preview looks fine, the captured video is only 352x288 in resolution, and is heavily distorted and although I can still recognize two instances of my face in it, it is flooded with bright green areas and it presents interlacing artifacts. Only Windows Media Player seems to fail at rendering this video, VLC and Quicktime shows a correctly rendered 352x288 video.

If I use the default renderer:

```
hr = mPBuild->RenderStream(
    &PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW,
    &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    mPCapVideo,
    NULL,
    NULL);

hr = mPBuild->RenderStream(
    &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,
    &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    mPCapVideo,
    NULL,
    mPMux);
```

The captured AVI has a size of 640x480, and all players are able to reproduce it properly, including Media Player.

It looks like VMR9 is imposing a video size on the entire graph, even for the captured file. This intuition is confirmed by the following code, placed right before the call to **IMediaControl::Run**:

```
IBasicVideo *pBasicVideo;
hr = mPGraph->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBasicVideo));
long w, h;
hr = pBasicVideo->GetVideoSize(&w, &h);
```

With the default renderer **w** and **h** are 640, 480 while with my VMR9 instance they are 352, 288.

** Edit **

The problem was that at some point, for some reason, the format of the output PIN of the camera switched from:

```
RGB24
352x288
```

To:

```
I420
352x288
```

And I guess Media Player has a problem with such format inside an AVI. An interesting fact is that the thumbnail of the video in Explorer was ok, and I could see the first frame with the right colors.

Comment: Do you properly set the resolution on the capture pin? Also, try what happens if you don't use the preview pin. In the past I have had different problems with the preview pin, now I am using the capture pin for preview too (using smart tee and resize filter).

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was with the video format and not simply with the resolution as I first guessed. However, this resize filter would be very useful in some circumstances, how do I instantiate one?

Comment: Take a look at the TransNull24 filter which is part of the RGBFilters example application in the directshow sdk. It can be used to force a RGB24 stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you connect two filters they must agree on a video format (including resolution). Different renderers may prefer different formats so you've got this behavior. You can query webcam's output pin for IAMStreamConfig interface to get a list of supported formats and select the one you need. Problems with playback of captured videos you had should have been caused by incorrect header: actual video format wasn't the one specified in the file header.

Comment: Thank you, you were right that the problem was the format, not really the resolution. Check the updated post.

Answer (score 2):

`RenderStream` is high level wrapper for other DirectShow API methods and it builds streaming pipeline (filter graph) for you filling missing pieces. Since it is actively using [Intelligent Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it might be adding new filters you are not aware of, including filters you don't want there, and filters that possibly affect media types (formats) on filters you already have by the time of the call.

This is the likely cause of your format changing from 640x480 to 352x288 for unknown reason. It is hard to guess what is the effective topology, and this is up to you to find it out. A more reliable way is to avoid `RenderStream` and build the graph in smaller increments in a more controllable way, by adding and connecting specific filters of your interest.

Comment: Thank you, I need to double check this, but it looks like **RenderStream** would build the *same* topology that I would build manually, but while doing so it would change the format of the output pin of the video source to something that Media Player and AVI together don't like.

Comment: You expect it to be the same, and then you need to review what is actually built. `RenderStream` does not offer you flexibility in fine tuning the build process.